# Regular Expression for Non decimal positive integer ranging between 0 to 999999

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I need the regular expression which matches all positive non decimal integers only range from 0 to 999999. It will not accept any decimal, alphabets or any special character and range should be in between 0 to 999999.

Comment: `\d{1,6}` - it is regexes 101. Please take 10 minutes and read basics

Comment: You really should go through a tutorial now and then, doesn't hurt.

Comment: Erm, you want non decimal integers, but no alphabetic characters? Example, please? :-)

Comment: We'd prefer it if you posted what you tried as well. It's not really fair on the community to ask us to solve your problem in this way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it.

```
Regex.IsMatch("999999","^[0-9]{0,6}$");//return true
```

Comment: accept? this will match 000123 is it OK?

Comment: Yes! He the OP is concerned about the value, not how its represented, I guess. So 000123 getting accepted is fine.